# Google Sheets: Return staff names in a comma delineated list; filtered by seasonal location and ranked by seniority

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-query-language, textjoin

I have an extensive Google Sheet database of staff; **First Name** (ColA), **date of availability** (ColB, their name appears once {ColA} for each date {ColB} they are available), **seasonal location** (E-H), **trip name knowledge base by area** (I-O) and **seniority** (Column D).

I also have lists of trips separated into seasons (Winter/Spring Trips tabs) with the specific days of each trip arranged in the corresponding row. These trips can only be completed by a staff member that is in the location of the trip during that season and has it listed in their knowledge base.
[Example Workbook.](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oLqULMnZ0gg_5ZIzp4w3h2G4AMMZgBCdUhuBjV_wHhs/edit#gid=0)

Ideally I would like sheets to list 'available staff' in one column (ColL on each "Season Trips" tab) with staff that have the task listed in their knowledge base & the area listed in their Seasonal location, ranked by seniority (5, 4, 3, 2, 1). There are also Summer/Fall Tabs that I will add if there is a way to make this all happen.

Answer (score 0):

paste in B2 and drag down:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(TEXTJOIN(", ", 1, UNIQUE(QUERY(TO_TEXT('Staff availability'!A:D), 
 "select Col1 
  where Col2 matches '"&TEXTJOIN("|", 1, TO_DATE(VLOOKUP(A2, 
 {'Winter Trips'!A:K; 'Spring Trips'!A:K}, SEQUENCE(1, 10, 2), 0)))&"' 
  order by Col4 desc", 0))), "no one"))
```

[image]

---

### update:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(TEXTJOIN(", ", 1, UNIQUE(QUERY(
 SUBSTITUTE(QUERY(TRIM(IFERROR(SPLIT(FLATTEN(IF('Staff availability'!E$2:O="",,TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE({"♦"&'Staff availability'!A$2:A, "♦♠"&TO_TEXT('Staff availability'!B$2:B), "♦"&'Staff availability'!C$2:D}),,9^9))&"♦"&'Staff availability'!E$2:O)), "♦"))), 
 "where Col5 = '"&QUERY(FILTER(INDIRECT("B1:B"&ROW()), INDIRECT("A1:A"&ROW())="-"), "offset "&COUNTA(FILTER(INDIRECT("B1:B"&ROW()), INDIRECT("A1:A"&ROW())="-"))-1)&"' 
     or Col5 contains '"&TRIM(A4)&"'"), "♠", ), 
 "select Col1 
  where Col2 matches '"&TEXTJOIN("|", 1, TO_DATE(VLOOKUP(A4, {'Winter Trips'!A:K; 'Spring Trips'!A:K}, SEQUENCE(1, 10, 2), 0)))&"' 
  order by Col4 desc", 0))), "no one"))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: dunno, but now I cant see (and debug) Shayne coz you rewrote it to Staff-0000 xD

Comment: ok, so shayne is listed there because he is listed under Flagstaff event. see Sheet8 eg thats the "seasonal location (E-H)"